# Show path instead of ID in link field result in SPE

Tags: powershell-extensions

I've modified one of the SPE 6.1.1 reports in 9.2 to add a column for a general link field, as our client wants to see which items have links and how old they are (based on the link location). But the value that comes back is the raw value (IE, `<link text="" anchor="" linktype="internal" class="" title=""  querystring="" id="{EB3C1FA5-57D5-42C2-A4B6-CA575F874C8E}" />`). Is there any out of the box way to retrieve the non-raw value or the item path behind that ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this to get a [strongly-typed field](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items#get-item-properties-with-field-type):

```powershell
$item.PSFields.MyCoolLink
```